# Can't get MSSQL table data with codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to get the data from the MSSQL table named "dbo.Events" in codeigniter 3.1.9

The connection to the database is established but the query failed.

```
$query = $this->db->get('dbo.Events');
return $query->result_array();
```

The result is the following:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: HY000/1
>   no such table: dbo.Events
>
> SELECT * FROM "dbo"."Events"
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/ci3/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

The Table exists and the name is correct.
How has the query to look like or how I have to escape the "." in the tablename?

edit:

```
$db['lardis_mssql'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => '192.168.120.xxx',
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'passowrd',
'database' => 'LardisLog',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => 'dbo.',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Tbh, I don't know about codeigniter, but do you really sure that you have a table named `Events` related to `dbo` schema? and you really targetting hte right database? (according to the error msg you don't have one really)

Comment: I am sure, because `SELECT * FROM dbo.Events` in the SQL Management Studio shows me the whole tables and there are other table named like for example "dbo.Users" or "dbo.Networks"

Comment: I have added the configuration from the database and added the prefix "dbo.", and removed the dbo from the query. but without success

Comment: remove the schema and remove the `dbprefix` in your configuration and try it again `$query = $this->db->get('Events');`

Comment: thx for you input, but it failed. perhaps there is something with the permission on the sql server? I have contacted the contacted the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I forgot to write, that the MSSQL is the second database to which I want to connect.

After several times of checking the configuration with the support of this page:
https://www.macamateri.com/2017/05/cara-koneksi-database-sql-server-mssql-di-codeigniter.html

The solution is quite simple:
I don't connect to correct database.

```
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->mssql_db = $this->load->database('lardis_mssql', TRUE);
  }

  public function get_tetra_log()
  {

  $get_where_array = array(
      "RadioID" => "******-*****-*****-****-**********"
  );

    $query = $this->mssql_db->get_where('Events', $get_where_array);
    return $query->result_array();
  }
```